# Why is the result null?（Entity Framework Core）

Tags: c#, linq, axios, entity-framework-core

I would like to update data using C# and Entity Framework Core.

But the result of Swagger is different from the result of executing the API in axios.

The variable "todoList" is stored with data in Swagger and returned **null** in axios.

Why a value of "todoList" is null?

Please tell me about it.

Thank you!

This is a Code.

```
public bool updateCompFlg(string operatorId, string id)
{
 // Call Update!
 // "_repository is an Interface."
 if (_repository.Update(operatorId, id))
 {
  return true;
 }
 else
 {
  return false;
 }
}
```

This is the code that actually updates the data.

```
public bool Update(string operatorId, string id)
{
 // ★The results here are different.
 var todoList = _context.TODOLIST.Where(u => u.seqNo.Equals(id)).FirstOfDefault();

 todoList.operatorId = operatorId;
 todoList.resultFlg = "1";

 _context.Update(todoList);

 try
 {
  _context.SaveChange();
  return true;
 }
 catch (SystemException ex)
 {
  throw ex;
 }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the requests are exactly same?

Comment: @viveknuna
Yes. We can also check the arguments in debugging to make sure they are correct.

Comment: have you checked the generated query? and compared both? and there is no exception as well?

Comment: @viveknuna
Yes. I have the API destination confirmed and the query confirmed, do I need to initialize the DataModel, etc.?

Comment: Inside your repository Update method, get the actual ConnectionString for the _context.Database at runtime and compare that with the database connection you expect it to be using. Often at runtime people don't notice that it's pulling a different connection string from config or such than what they expect and it ends up reading from a different database all-together.

Comment: @StevePy
So does that mean I need to connect the DB context with connectString?

Comment: No, it's just to get the actual connection string that the DbContext is using at runtime. For EF6 (.net Framework) use `var connectionString = _context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;` for EF Core use `var connectionString = _context.Database.GetConnectionString();`  Inspect that value with a breakpoint and check that it matches the database connection you are using to check whether data is updated or not.  If it's wrong you need to look at how you are supplying a connection string to EF. Often this is a missing config update. (I.e. updated in a DLL config but not the app's config)

Comment: @StevePy
When checked one by one, the wrong value was stored in the argument. Therefore, the todoList was null. We apologize for taking so much time.